# Does a reference exist for the A Song of Ice and Fire (Game of Thrones)?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

My wife and I have begun to read [Game of Thrones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553386794) the first book in the series [A Song of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire). We purchased the [four book bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JN1D2I) for our [Kindles](https://kindle.amazon.com/), but with the large number of characters and spiraling landscape are having a hard time keeping everyone and everything straight. From experience,<sup>1</sup> I know that many books with this intricate of a plot have detailed appendices and maps. Having the first four books in the series as a giant blob on our Kindles might be masking a printed appendix at the back.

As such I am curious do any fan created or official wikis, encyclopedias, or reference materials exist for the series? Thus far my [Google-Fu](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=google-fu) has not turned up anything of exceptional value.

<sub>1. e.g. [Lord of the Rings](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/), [Wheel of Time](http://www.encyclopaedia-wot.org/), [Dune](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Appendix_I%3a_The_Ecology_of_Dune)</sub>

Comment: Read them once, don't worry too much about getting confused, then go back and read them again...  I'm on my third reading, after starting last fall.

Comment: Each book has an appendix listing houses and their affiliated characters. And the books have maps (although not enough of them) — mostly at the beginning, sometimes at the end. Each book in the Kindle blob has a table of contents, so you should be able to find the maps and appendices fairly easily.

Comment: @sjl I didn't even think to look at the TOC in the Kinle blob. Ive gotten so used to just starting to read it didn't even occur to me. Not good when technology starts to make you dumber.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is it possible that your google-fu has missed westeros.org?

http://awoiaf.westeros.org/

They also have various forums, and are actually referenced by GRRM himself, who has a rarely-used user in the forums. His wife posts there from time to time.

Be aware that there will be spoilers!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the spoilers I will be diligent. This website is a good example of why using an image for your heading is a bad idea when it comes to search engine optimization.

Comment: If spoilers are a concern, they have multiple forum sections with varying levels of "spoilyness" where one can ask questions without much risk of reading something one does not want to. They are very adamant about such things.

Comment: @ahsteele You're welcome.

Answer (score 15):

As well as westeros.org, there is the [Tower of the Hand](http://towerofthehand.com/), which has a pretty cool feature: it has selectable **spoiler levels**. In many sections (e.g. character reference pages) they ask you which book you've read so far (they call it "scope"), and everything spoilerish gets hidden from you.

Comment: That sounds like an awesome feature! Seems so obvious tragic that more sites don't follow suite.

Answer (score 4):

There *is* an appendix at the end of each book for your Kindle.  I read all of the books on my Kindle and it's there.  Not easy to get to if you're trying to reference it in the middle of the book, but it breaks all the characters down into their houses, gives some history and genealogy.

Comment: That is present in the physical books as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official resource I know of but the creators [westeros.org](http://www.westeros.org/About/) have since become the co-authors of The World of Ice and Fire alongside George R. R. Martin and so that is a canon book. As such this is the go to site. As well as general information the site contains lots of useful information including concordance, so spake Martin and many other useful features. However, the parts that are likely to be most help to you are:

- [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Main_Page): A wiki that has breakdowns of all the characters/events/places and is very well referenced.
- [A Forum of Ice and Fire](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/): Similar to SFF but dedicated to ASOIAF you willf ind a lot of help there and it is more discussion based than our platform.
- [The Citadel](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/): This contains a lot of extra information given by Martin outside of the series so is helpful to look through every now and then.

Outside of that The Lands of Ice and Fire is a series of canon maps detailing the world to help you visualise the geography. A lot of the maps are available [online here](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/the-lands-of-ice-and-fire/).

---

If that doesn't help you still the Tag wikis also contain some further links.

- [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/a-song-of-ice-and-fire/info)
- [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/game-of-thrones/info)

---

Aside from those resources I have also heard of the following though I'm not sure how accurate they are or how well used.

- [Tower of the Hand](https://towerofthehand.com/)
- [Ice and Fire wikia](http://iceandfire.wikia.com/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_Wiki)
- [Game of Thrones wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_Wiki): It is for the show but is sometimes helpful and also contains "In the Books" sections.